# Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and now it keeps shutting off my modem/router

Tags: router, 22.04

Upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 22.04 from 21.10. It will connect to the internet slowly for a few minutes but then completely shuts off the router. My other devices work fine, but this one is making it impossible for other devices to use the internet while this one is trying to connect. (it took me several tries to post this.)

I am technologically challenged, so please dumb it down for me.

Comment: Have you power-cycled the router?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl systemd-dnsmasq`.

Comment: @waltinator, the OP clearly stated "I am technologically challenged, so please dumb it down for me."